# Neo4j Cluster Stuck "Attempting to connect to the other cluster members"

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I am trying to get a Neo4j cluster running with docker-compose.
When I start it up, the cluster members get stuck "Attempting to connect to the other cluster members before continuing..."

I also tried running with plain docker as described in these docs with the same result:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/#docker-cc

Has anyone had success running a cluster with docker?

Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  lan:

services:

  core1:
    image: neo4j:3.4.6-enterprise
    networks:
      - lan
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 6477:6477
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/conf:/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes      
      - NEO4J_causal_clustering_minimum_core_cluster_size_at_formation=2
      - NEO4J_causalClustering_initialDiscoveryMembers=core1:5000,core2:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687

  core2:
    image: neo4j:3.4.6-enterprise
    networks:
      - lan
    ports:
      - 7475:7475
      - 6478:6478      
      - 7688:7688      
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core2/conf:/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core2/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core2/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/plugins:/plugins      
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes      
      - NEO4J_causal_clustering_minimum_core_cluster_size_at_formation=2
      - NEO4J_causalClustering_initialDiscoveryMembers=core1:5000,core2:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7475
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6478
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7688
```